# Redirecting forked process output to parent process in C

Tags: c, fork, stdout, stdin, pipe

What I am implementing is a (simpler) version of bash.  One of the tasks is to accept the command :

```
$ bg <command> <arguments>
```

This will then fork a new process and then run `execvp()` in the new process using `<command>` and `<arguments>` as parameters.  The problem is that when I capture the output from the child process, I use `pipe()`, and after getting the output from the child process and outputting it when I want, I can't seem to switch back to `STDIN` for my parent (shell) process, which results in a segfault the next time I need to accept input.

Here is part of my "bg" function.

```
ChildPID = fork();
if (ChildPID < 0) {
 /* There is an error */
 printf("Error forking the process.\n");
 exit(1);
}
if (ChildPID >= 0) {
 if (ChildPID == 0) {  /* Child Process */
  close(m_pipefd[0]);
  dup2(m_pipefd[1], STDOUT_FILENO);
  close(m_pipefd[1]);
  //sleep(5);
         err = execvp(optionsPTR[0], optionsPTR);
  switch (errno) {
   case ENOENT:
    printf("RSI: %s: command not found\n", optionsPTR[0]);
    break;
   case EACCES:
    printf("RSI: %s: Permission denied\n", optionsPTR[0]);
    break;
  }
  exit(1);
 }
 else {  /* Parent Process */
  WaitErr = waitpid(ChildPID, &status, WNOHANG | WUNTRACED);
                return(0); /* to main */
        }
}
return 0;
```

And the code for when I get the output from the pipe after the process finishes.

```
close(m_pipefd[1]);     
dup2(m_pipefd[0], STDIN_FILENO);
while(fgets(buffer, sizeof(buffer), stdin)) {
 buf = buffer;
 printf("%s\n", buf);
}
close(m_pipefd[0]);
```

So the tl;dr version is that I need to reset back to stdin for the parent process after capturing the child processes output.

Thanks,

Braden

Answer (score 3):

There is usually no need to mess with stdin and stdout in your parent.  After you connect your pipes in the *child* to stdin and stdout, the other ends of the pipes should be able to send data or get data from the child.

Just read from m_pipefd[1] in your parent.

Comment: Thanks, I don't know what I was thinking.  That fixed it.